# 'Help someone 'with' something' - is it always the structure?

Tags: sentence-construction

These sentences are commonly found on the Internet and in the books...

> My mother helped me with homework. 
>   My sister helped me with shopping.

Is it always like that? *"....helped [someone] **with** [something]...*

Are these correct?

> My sister helped me *in* (doing) shopping. 
>   There were many options (of whatever) to go for but my mother helped me *in* selection.

What if my sister has a better tool to unscrew a nut in a robo to dismantle it?

> It was very difficult to dismantle the little robo. My sister *helped me with a tool* and we could do that job easily!

The above sentence uses *with* but than the context is different!

Comment: with homework(noun), with shopping(gerund), in doing homework(verb)

Comment: You could also use [help out](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/help-out) though the meaning is a bit more implied.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use "with", as in your sentences,"My mother helped me with(my) homework." 
"My sister helped me with the shopping" or full or bare infinitve.Example:"My mother helped me to do/do my homework."My mother helped me to do/do the shopping."

Also:My sister helped me by giving me with a tool, so we could do that job easily.
"Help"+in(gerund) is not correct.